# fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines, guideline-support-library

I tried including the gsl.h for hands on purpose in my VS2013. When I try to build the project, it says

> c:\users\njain6\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\gcldemo\string_span.h(336): fatal error C1001: An
>   internal error has occurred in the compiler.

Steps I followed:

1. I downloaded the zip files from Github.
2. Extracted the zip to a folder in the project folder.
3. Included the gsl headers in the project.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: This is a compiler problem. Locate the problem code and report it to MS Connect.

Comment: Congratulations, you found a compiler bug! Try minimizing the test case, and reporting it to Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

This is because they are only supported on VS 2015 Update 1 and later. You need to:1) Load your solution into VS2015 Update 1 (or2). 2) Upgrade/re-target the solution to use the VS2015 toolchain. You will then find that it works.